# React.js: Stop render from scrolling to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Every time you perform a render in React.js, the UI scrolls to the top of the page.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/dcfy5xrd/

Any nifty or *reactive* way to stop that?

E.g. If a User scrolls down the page, then pushes a button which causes a Render, the UI would stay in the same scroll location as before.

```
// Forces a render which scrolls to top of page
this.setState({data: data});
```

UPDATE: Why does the UI scroll to the top for some renders, but not others?

Comment: Could you provide a JSBin/JSFiddle that illustrates this? It hasn't happened in any of my React applications.

Comment: This can happen when the scrolled dom node is unmounted and remounted. Make sure that the `key` / parent tree of the corresponding element does not change between renders.

Comment: @Morhaus But what if you need the key/parent tree of the corresponding element to change between renders. E.g. User adds a row to a table, and then you fire a render adding that row. Is there any way to stop the "scroll to top" consequence?

Comment: @Morhaus So I double checked, and the keys of the elements being changed during render are not changing - only their values. This is strange, because if you call a render on **some** things on the page, it will not scroll to top.

Comment: As Anders said, please provide a minimal example of your issue in a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Morhaus - here is the minimal code example. [http://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/dcfy5xrd/](http://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/dcfy5xrd/)

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle. Just scroll down a bit in the UI and then click an arrow button. http://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/dcfy5xrd/

Comment: In my case gatsby was the problem, I solved it by adding `gatsby-browser.js` with `exports.shouldUpdateScroll = () => false`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@floydophone answered this one on Twitter.

https://twitter.com/floydophone/status/608129119025561600

> @bengrunfeld @reactjs you forgot `preventDefault()` on your link handlers

Comment: even after `e.preventDefault()` it is scrolling back to top

Comment: Do you actually have that argument in your handler function? `function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: For me the issue was that I used a `<form>` element and on click of the enclosed `<button>` it jumped to the top. Since I didn't really use the `<form>`, I just replaced it by a `<div>` and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Just confirming that in 2020 e.preventDefault() still doesn't do anything to solve this problem.

Comment: I second this ^^^

Answer (score 23):

Ok if anyone read this , in my case the problem wasn't any of above. You must try first suggestions on above any way. I did everything including `preventDefault()` but didn't help me. The problem was ; using `styled-components`. Because, styled-components give a random classname every render. So it resets scroll. I gave the class name from css and solved my problem.

Comment: That should only happen if you create styled components _inside_ your component. Which you should not do. Create your styled-components outside your component and the class is never changed.

Comment: I have exactly same issue and was *wondering* why LOL, thanks for saving some energy

Comment: @Alex thanks, being kinda new to hooks, I get it completely. There were functional components declared within a functional component. Hence redeclaring those inside on each rerender caused the above problem.

Comment: Refactoring into independent (not nested) components resolved so many problems including this one. Feels like React should just not allow it at all.

Answer (score 5):

Wanted to add here for those who are not using anchor tags, `preventDefault` will not save you. As bizarre as it is, for me it was related to rendering my child components inside a `div` with

```
display:table > display:tablecell
```

For some reason the child component's scroll position is lost in this situation when there is any re-render. Problem vanished when I switched to flexbox (display:flex).

Comment: For me I had `@supports (display: grid) { display: grid; }` for my child grid components inside a div which was doing it. Thanks for this answer from back in 2016. It has fixed an issue I have been looking at for a whole day!

Answer (score 1):

If render trigger scrolling to the top it usually means some UI component is changing its dimension because of the state, this can be fixed by adding a minimum width/height

Answer (score 1):

This could be happening because of the change in redux state, which will show the changes everywhere in the code where it is getting used. **Try making the change using the local state of that component on action of which, the page is getting scrolled.**

Comment: If this really happens, there ought to be a flashing red warning at the top of the redux documentation. I suspect you're right. I am converting an app to use redux and I can't get the scroll behavior to work. Any idea where in the redux code I could put a breakpoint to check if this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

**2022 Hacky Solution:**

I couldn't find a way to completely prevent the scrolling on the re-render.  `preventDefault` didn't help, and I didn't have access to the specific element structure, but I did have the className of the scrolling element.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const el = document.getElementsByClassName('my-classname')?.[0];
  const newTimeoutRef = setTimeout(() => el?.scrollTo(0, scrollTop), 50);
  return () => clearTimeout(newTimeoutRef);
}, [scrollTop]);
```

Then you set the `scrollTop` (as a component state) inside the event that was previously causing the scroll to top.

The hack here is that `setTimeout`, which basically gives the DOM time to scroll to the top before calling your `el.scrollTo`, it flashes a bit, but it was the best solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

yeah I can confirm, if you wrap each styled-element inside a div with the same key attribute it will prevent the page from scrolling, for example:

```
<div key="A"><Doughnut data={data} /></div>
<div key="A"><Doughnut data={data} /></div>
```