# Updating parent UI with onClick and setState scrolls up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Specifically, my problem is that I have a toggle button which I use to toggle between two UIs one is higher. And this toggle button is a child to the updated UI. When I scroll down a bit from the main UI and toggle to the higher view, it scrolls up. It doesn't do it other way around and when the scroll location is above the main UI.

To see it in action, [click to this development version of the project](http://www.iupui.edu/~sysbio/seten/), select an item under `Explore panel` on the left, scroll down a bit, and click the toggle button next to `Compare` on the right.

It only scrolls up when I update from a lower UI to higher UI.

[I read on SO that not having `preventDefault()` can be the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365818/react-js-stop-render-from-scrolling-to-top-of-page), but I have it from the beginning.

My handler is:

```
handleCompareToggleClick: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({compare: !this.state.compare});
},
```

Actually, my source code is huge so you can find it [here](https://github.com/gungorbudak/seten/tree/master/assets/js/src). The toggle button belongs to `ResultGroupTitle` and the updated UI is `ResultGroup`.

Comment: were you able to solve this. I am facing a similar issue. even after e.preventDefault() it is scrolling back to top

Comment: @vipin8169 Nope. I still have the same issue. The funny thing is it only does it for one toggle, not for the other click. I actually deleted tat development version and updated in my question

Comment: Could you solve this ?  The page seems to work fine now.

Comment: @jhegedus it works indeed. As far as I remember I just moved the components into individual JSX files and maybe upgraded React version (didn't use v15 at that time it felt a bit slow). I didn't really do anything to solve it but yes it seems it's good now. Maybe it was browser issue and has been solved recently. Wish I added more details to my question back then like browser version and stuff.

Comment: In my case, there was a `window.scrollTo` I forgot about in another component on the same page. Every time the page updated the component would cause a scroll.