# Prevent Browser from scrolling to top

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function to handle new props in my component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.setState({
            songTitles: newProps.songTitles,
            queue: newProps.songQueue
        });
}
```

and the following render function:

```
render() {
        return(
            <div id="attendee-queue" ref='attendeequeue'>
                <div id="attendee-queue-list">
                {   this.state.songTitles.map((title, i) => {
                        return  <div key={i}>
                                    <div className={this.getDivClass(i) + " attendee-songOuterDiv songPlaying hvr-back-pulse2"}>
                                        <a target="_blank" href={"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+this.state.queue[i]}>
                                            <div className="attendee-songInnerDiv"
                                                 onMouseEnter={() => this.handleHoverQueue.bind(i)}
                                                 onMouseLeave={this.handleUnhoverQueue}>
                                                {(this.state.hoverQueueId == i) ? 
                                                    {title}
                                                :
                                                    <p>{title}</p>
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    })
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

But everytime the props for the component change, the browser automatically scrolls to top. I want to prevent this from happening and have the user stay at the same scroll position as they were.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365818/react-js-stop-render-from-scrolling-to-top-of-page) post but I don't think I have an event I can use preventDefault from.

For reference these are some of my other functions:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        songTitles: props.songTitles,
        hoverQueueId: -1,
        queue: props.songQueue
    };
    this.scroll = Scroll.animateScroll;
    this.handleHoverQueue = this.handleHoverQueue.bind(this);
    this.handleUnhoverQueue = this.handleUnhoverQueue.bind(this);
}
handleHoverQueue() {
    this.setState({hoverQueueId:i});
}
handleUnhoverQueue(){
    this.setState({hoverQueueId: -1});
}
getDivClass(i){
    return "divNotHovered";
}
```

These are my imports:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  Image
} from 'reactstrap';
import {
  formatDateTime
} from '../timeConverter.js';
import Scroll from 'react-scroll';
var url = 'https://djque.herokuapp.com/?query=';
require("../resources/css/eventList.css");
```