# React.js: Data update causes scroll to top on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Let me start of by saying that the problem I'm facing is very similar to that of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365818/react-js-stop-render-from-scrolling-to-top-of-page). Essentially, my interface contains a list with data in it, and the interface scrolls to the top of the page every time something re-renders or every time a button is pressed. **However**, this only happens on iOS. I have tested this on Chrome on Windows, Chrome and Safari on OS X, Chrome on Android, as well as Chrome and Safari on iOS. I only get this problem on iOS.

Another detail in my case is that I am using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) to manage state, and this state is updated continuously using [Server Sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) from a back end. This means that the list can be updated at any time if new data is pushed from the back end, i.e. no interaction with the interface is required.

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365818/react-js-stop-render-from-scrolling-to-top-of-page) mentioned using `preventDefault()` to handle this problem, but like many have mentioned, this has not worked for me. Furthermore it wouldn't work in all cases since the re-renders don't always happen because of an `onclick` or similar.

Could anybody help me shed some light on why this problem occurs on iOS but not elsewhere, and hopefully also provide a solution to fix it? Below you will find some snippets of my code with the relevant components for this problem. Thank you.

React.js code:

```js
import React from 'react';

import styles from './listView.module.css';

class ListView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let list;
    if (isSuccess(this.props.list)) { //Checks that SSE->Redux State was successful
      list = getData(this.props.list.data);
    }
    return (
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        {isSuccess(this.props.list) && (
          <div className={styles.scrollWrapper}>
            <div className={styles.listWrapper}>
              {list.map((entry) => (
                <ListEntry key={entry.id} data={entry.data}/>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
  }
}
```

CSS:

```css
html {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10px 1fr 10px;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 105px);
}

.scrollWrapper {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: span 1;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /*Momentum scrolling on iOS*/
}

.scrollWrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.listWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Few details for helping you, but maybe there's a small time while your `list` var is empty, so React render an empty _div_.
This can be enough for the browser to reduce the page height and maybe on iOS this prevent the scroll to be restored when the div is full again.
I suggest you to check if `list` is rendered as empty during the fetch process.

Comment: @keul Do you mean that it would only render the div with `styles.wrapper` since `isSuccess` returns false? Every time it will utilize `list` when rendering, the variable will be populated. `isSuccess` doesn't toggle between fetches so `list` should never be empty when the render function is finished, as long as no error occurred.. 

Sorry if I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: yes, this is what I meant. Are you sure it is never empty? Just try to add a `console.log(list)` after the "if" and check in the browser console if it's always filled

Comment: @keul It is empty when the site is rendered the first time (i.e. before the first fetch is finished). It is never empty after that. When a new SSE event fires, the component re-renders with the updated information (and the scroll resets to the top on iOS), but the list is never empty, according to the `console.log(list)`.

Comment: sorry, I've no more clues. Try to google for "react restore scroll position" ‍♂️